# vite npm run dev error Cannot read file "node_modules/react/jsx-dev-runtime.js": Access is denied.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, vite, react-dom

I created a vite app successfully. When I run the app with npm run dev, I get these three errors :
**[ERROR] Cannot read file "node_modules/react/jsx-dev-runtime.js": Access is denied.
X [ERROR] Cannot read file "node_modules/react/index.js": Access is denied.
X [ERROR] Cannot read file "node_modules/react-dom/client.js": Access is denied.**

I have deleted my node_modules and package-lock files severally. I have created another Vite React app and still get this error.
My various files.

**package.json file**

```
 {
  "name": "my-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

**Vite.config.jsf file**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

**Main.jsx file**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue? I have been on this for the past three days now surfing the net. I will be available to provide any other information needed.

node version: 18.12.2
react version: 18.2.0
npm version:9.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your powershell (or whatever terminal you are using).

You need to open it **as administrator** in order to be able to do the required actions

Comment: I am using vscode.

Comment: @Muhamed Mostafa. That was the issue. Thanks. I didn't use to run vs code as an administrator. I assume that it should have that right. But when I did now, it ran successfully.

Comment: May you please upvote and marke as resolved ?  :`D